# "Obliged to do something" vs "obliged to doing something"

Tags: difference

Tell me please the difference between the following sentences.

> I am obliged **to do** the work.
>
> I am obliged **to doing** the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Obliged to do something* is correct:

> It was raining, so I felt **obliged to invite** him into the house.
>
> Employers are legally **obliged to pay** the minimum wage.
>
> Circumstances had **obliged** him **to sell** the business.

So, use the to-infinitive after *oblige*.

Comment: However, you can also be obliged **to be doing something**, meaning **to be occupied or busy with something**.

Comment: Also, obliged _to_ someone _for doing_ something

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *I am obliged to do the work.*
>
> [2] *I am obliged to doing the work.*

The difference is that only [1] is correct. The PP with a gerund-participial clause as complement in [2] does not satisfy the complement requirement of "oblige".

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that the gerund form after adjectives is used *only if* they are followed by prepositions, for example: famous for/tired of/proud of doing something. In your sentence "to", following the adjective *obliged*, is not a preposition but the sign of the infinitive case. Besides, the sheer definition of (to be) obliged is (to be) *under a moral obligation **to do** something.*